# Using Google Maps Directions API in android - what kind of API key is needed?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm embedding a map into my Android App and want to make it draw a route between two points. However, I have no clue, how to get a correct key for Directions Api - the server returns ***"error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid."*** as I'm trying to get the route via http request and using my android api key (a simple map and geolocation are working well with it).
The request is (got from google docs examples):
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=place_id:ChIJ685WIFYViEgRHlHvBbiD5nE&destination=place_id:ChIJA01I-8YVhkgRGJb0fW4UX7Y&key=MyActualAndroidKey`

So, the **question** is:

- What key type is relevant for using Directions Api in Android -
  android, server, browser key?
- Do I have to turn particular options
  in the google console? The Google Maps Directions API is enabled in
  the console already.
- If the key is OK, what's the reason of servers    denial to handle
  the request?

### UPDATE

As API v. 3 do not prohibit using requests without key, the things work well without defining the key parameter in the query. But it works not for all requests, and the request above won't work. Apparently, query like http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los%20Angeles,CA&sensor=false" works everywhere, including a browser. The difference between queries is in using place_id - it's possible to use it only with key.

Answer (score 1):

yes. Obviously the key type should be server or none because you are using the web url (like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?) instead of mobile sdk.

Mobile(Key restriction type is either **Android or iOS**) API key will be required only when we use on mobile sdk to fetch and manipulate the google map feature.

Note:
Key restriction type **None** will be supported for all platform but recommended is specific type of restriction based on platform.

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated google direction api in one of my project and I have use server key for that.

go to https://console.developers.google.com
enable google direction API
create a server key
user same key in the android to call direction API

Comment: Simple switching of the keys doesn't affect the server response - it returns the same. Can you provide a code sample, please?